# ORA-24373 When I try to run a query from VBscript

Tags: sql, oracle, vbscript, oracle11g, oracle-objects-ole

I am getting the following error

> ORA-24373: invalid length specified for statement

The sql that I am trying to execute is a simple update query

```sql
UPDATE Table1 SET C_LOGIN ='HIS LOGIN' Where C_USER='HIS'
```

I only get this error when I try to run the ExecuteSQl method from VBScript. But there is no error when I run the query in SQLDeveloper. I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: The query as shown is fine so the error will be in the VB.NET code. Please add the VB.NET code to your question.

Comment: @EdGibbs VBScript is not VB.Net they are a both completely different, one is a scripting language the other is a fully fledged programming language.

Comment: What is the size of the column `C_LOGIN` in `Table1`? That error occurs when the field is too small to fit the data you are attempting to set.

Comment: Please show us your VBSctipt code.

Comment: `ExecuteSQL()` isn't a VBScript method or ADODB one for that matter so you must be using something else. From the looks of it you might be using [Oracle Objects for OLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e17727/toc.htm) specifically the [ExecuteSQL Method](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e17727/sermthod086.htm#OOFOL546). Why not just use an Oracle provider with ADODB that way you can use standard methods for working with your data?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit judging by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40798206/692942) posted at a similar time they are using Oracle Objects for OLE COM automation library in VBScript.

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart - 100% correct; I misread the language.